# When does $\omega \cdot \alpha = \alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

A proof I am looking at mentions the special case that  $\omega \cdot \alpha = \alpha$, but for what ordinals $\alpha$ is  this the case?

Comment: Are you familiar with Cantor normal form?

Comment: See also: [Multiplicatively indecomposable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additively_indecomposable_ordinal#Multiplicatively_indecomposable)

Comment: Conjecture: When alpha + alpha = alpha, or (not equivalently) alpha includes two alphas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha=\omega^\omega\cdot \beta$ for some ordinal $\beta$, then clearly $\omega\cdot \alpha=\alpha$. By considering the Cantor normal form of $\alpha$ (or, even better, by writing $\alpha$ in base-$\omega^\omega$ positional numeral system),  we obtain that $\alpha=\omega^\omega\cdot \beta$ is also necessary.